# SQL - How to insert into table based on id's found in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would need something like this pseudo code:

Comment: I'm not sure what `WHERE USERID = CURRENTLISTITEM` means in an `insert`. Is this an `insert` (new row) or an `update` (change to existing row)?

Comment: Sorry my bad, here's the correct syntax;

FOREACH USERID FOUND IN (SELECT DISTINCT USERID FROM USERAUTHORIZATIONS WHERE AUTHID <> 11)
 INSERT INTO USERAUTHORIZATIONS (USERID, AUTHID) VALUES (USERID, 11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for something like

```
INSERT INTO userauthorizations
 SELECT DISTINCT userid, 11
 FROM userauthorizations ua1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT *
  FROM userauthorizations ua2 
  WHERE ua2.userid = ua1.userid 
   AND ua2.authid = 11)
```

This will find all users who do not currently have a `authid`=11 and add a row for that `userid` with authid=11.

Note that this is different from your pseudocode `(SELECT DISTINCT USERID FROM USERAUTHORIZATIONS WHERE AUTHID <> 11)`, which finds users who have at least one entry that isn't `authid`=11.